# lxml Install Blocking Install of Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, lxml

How can I uninstall lxml so that Scrapy will install? `pip unintall lxml` will not work as shown in the code below.

After looking around for the best method to parse XML I stumbled upon Scrapy. I'm new to programming so the Scrapy documentation make the process much easier. In order to use it, it seems as though lxml needs to go. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Parthenon:~ Owner$ pip uninstall lxml
Cannot uninstall requirement lxml, not installed
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Owner/Library/Logs/pip.log

Parthenon:~ Owner$ pip install scrapy
Downloading/unpacking scrapy
Downloading Scrapy-0.24.4-py2-none-any.whl (444kB): 444kB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in         
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.5.2 (from scrapy)
Downloading six-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking queuelib (from scrapy)
Downloading queuelib-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking lxml (from scrapy)

pip can't proceed with requirement 'lxml (from scrapy)' due to a pre-existing build   
directory.
location: /private/var/folders/z_/00h47x3s6ql28yw7tm_l5ts80000gn/T/pip_build_Owner/lxml
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this. 
Please delete it and try again.

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Owner/Library/Logs/pip.log
Parthenon:~ Owner$
```

Comment: did you try deleting the specified directory?

Comment: Like I said I'm still getting my bearings. I would like to delete the directory. However, I don't know how to find and delete it in Terminal.

Comment: just run `rm -rf /private/var/folders/z_/00h47x3s6ql28yw7tm_l5ts80000gn/T/pip_build_Owner/lxml` and you'll be all set

Comment: Please use virtualenv to install Python packages, do not install them to your system Python installation https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: Thanks Matt, I appreciate it. And I will work only in virtualenv from now on.